# Angular 7 ngModelChange not triggering

Tags: angular

Im trying to call a function on ngModelChange when my input property binding is changed inside my parent component but it doesn't work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-bp1736

How am I supposed to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```html
 <select [(ngModel)]="teste" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

use (no "banana-in-a-box"):

```html
 <select [ngModel]="teste" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

[image]

In your stackblitz demo you're trying to update `ngModel` by switching the value of `teste` variable ***and apparently, per comments, you're expecting `ngModelChange` to fire because of it***. It won't happen. `ngModelChange` will fire when the component changes the value of `teste`, not when `teste` updates the value of `ngModel`.

If you want to run any method when `teste` changes, you could:
  1. Observe changes in the control value
  2. Use a setter/getter

### 1. Observe changes in the control

```html
<select [ngModel]="teste" #justATest="ngModel" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
```

Then, on typescript:

```js
@ViewChild('justATest'): _ngModelMonitoring: NgModel;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this._ngModelMonitoring.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
}
```

### 2. Use a setter/getter

```js
private _teste: string;
@Input()
get teste() { return this._teste; } 
set teste(value: string) {
  this._teste = value;
  console.log('Teste value changed: ', value);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. I've opened your stackblitz and recorded it. Take a look at my answer again as I added a gif.

Comment: Oh, now I got what you're trying to do... hahahah. I'm gonna update my answer.