# ngModelChange does not fired when value was changed manually

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following `input`

```
 //html 
 <input (ngModelChange)="onSelection()"  [(ngModel)]="selectedNode" >

// in the ts file

  onSelection() {
    alert('changed');
  }
```

When I type something inside the input, the `onSelection` methods is called. But When I try to set `selectedNode` by another methods the function is not triggered.

For example I added these codes:

```
 // html 
 <button (click)="settest();">
      click to change value (but does not fire ngModelChange)
 </button>  

 //ts
 settest() {
   this.selectedNode = 'test';
 }
```

I expect when I call the `settest()` methods `ngModelChange` fires but that is not happened. Why?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-yruac4?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-y4zlam?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html   Since, you have already provided the [(ngModel)], `selectedNode` has the two way binding and value gets updated

Comment: @Vijay it's still not working

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491123/angular-7-ngmodelchange-not-triggering

Comment: Downvoter please give me some feedback. What is wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kind of curious about this question so I debug it a little bit. The reason turned out is shockingly simple: They are just 2 different things.

1. The event binding: `(ngModelChange)` is triggered by [ViewToModelUpdate](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#viewtomodelupdate) comes from `DefaultValueAccessor (image below)`
2. Your `settest` is a `click` event, you see, click event isn't handled by `DefaultValueAccessor` (or in general ControlValueAccessor), so no trigger on modelChange

If none of the above make any sense to you. The key take away is: when typing in -> it's `View->Model` which is very different from `setting the model directly` as you do in your click handler.

[image]

[For more info about ControlValueAccessor and ViewToModel/ModelToView](https://indepth.dev/posts/1055/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms)

Edited with some kind of eli5:

1. First case: When you enter some text into the input. You're telling angular: hey angular, I've got this text (view), help me set it to my class property (model). Angular needs the help of DefaultValueAccessor to do the job: View -> DefaultValueAccessor (along the way fire the event ngModelChange) -> Model.
2. Same story for the second case: Hey angular, user clicked this button. Angular got it and run the click handler function which in turn simple set: class' property = new value - No DefaultValueAccessor get involved no ngModelChange event triggered

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I am curious why angular does not handle this? and secondly, how can I involve `DefaultValueAccessor` to tell to angular please fire the `ngModelChange` event :)

Comment: The question is why angular need to? :D why another middle step while it could do just this: property = value. Please take notice that you should step into angular's shoe to see this. Angular use Forms directive like NgModel to control forms, click to handle user click event (generally speaking). "Right tool for the right job" they say

Comment: If you want to implement your own custom input, I suggest you read the article link above. In case you want to trigger ngModelChange manually, you can call viewToModelUpdate method directly from NgModel. First: add a template ref in your template file: `#t="ngModel"` pass this value to settest(t) or use `ViewChild`, in the settest body, you could use t.viewToModelUpdate('new val')